# How to write sql query to get items from range

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get values without the smallest and the biggest ones, so without entry with 2 and 29 in column NumberOfRepeating.

[image]

My query is:

```
SELECT Note, COUNT(*) as 'NumberOfRepeating'
  WHERE COUNT(*) <> MAX(COUNT(*))AND COUNT(*) <> MIN(COUNT(*))
   FROM Note GROUP BY Note;
```

Comment: Wrong order, FROM comes before WHERE. (And put aggregate function conditions in HAVING.)

Comment: It sounds like a solution. Could you post it as an answer ?

Comment: `SELECT note, COUNT(*) as 'NumberOfRepeating' 
FROM Notes
GROUP BY note
HAVING COUNT(*) < MAX(COUNT(*)) AND COUNT(*) > MIN(COUNT(*)) ;`

Comment: I did this, but getting an error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT Note, COUNT(*) as 'NumberOfRepeating'
FROM Notes

GROUP BY Note
HAVING count(*) < 
(

SELECT max(t.maxi)
FROM (select
Note, COUNT(Note) maxi FROM Notes
 GROUP BY Note
 ) as t 
)

 AND
 count(*) >
(

SELECT min(t.min)
FROM (select
Note, COUNT(Note) min FROM Notes
 GROUP BY Note
 ) as t 
)
```

try this code.

Answer (score 0):

One method would use `order by` and `limit`, twice:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by NumberOfRepeating asc
      limit 99999999 offset 1
     ) t
order by NumberOfRepeating desc
limit 99999999 offset 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this code,

```
Select * from Note where NumberOfRepeating < (select MAX(NumberOfRepeating) from Note ) AND NumberOfRepeating > (select MIN(NumberOfRepeating) from Note );
```

Here in the code, as in your table `Note` is the name of the table, and `NumberOfRepeating` is the column name, as in your table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I got the result showed on the picture below after executing the following query:`SELECT Note, COUNT(*) as 'NumberOfRepeating'
   FROM Note GROUP BY Note;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT Note, COUNT(*) as 'NumberOfRepeating'
      FROM Notes 
      GROUP BY Note
      ORDER BY NumberOfRepeating DESC
      LIMIT 1, 2147483647
    ) T1
ORDER BY T1.NumberOfRepeating
LIMIT 1, 2147483647
```